# Proving a the squared of a sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a sequence $\{a_n\}$  converges to $1$, can you prove that $\{a_n\}^2$ converges as well? If possible, how? I know the definition of convergence but I am stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Consider the difference $a_n^2-1 = (a_n-1)(a_n+1)$. What happens with these factors as $n$ goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

We have that
$$
|a_n^2-1|=|a_n-1||a_n+1|\to0
$$
since $|a_n-1|\to0$ and $|a_n+1|\to2$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $a_n^2\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Actually, much more is true. If $f$ is a continuous function and $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$, then $f(a_n)\to f(a)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, helped a lot.

Comment: @BobBuild You're welcome! Since you're new to the site, I'd like to remind you that you can [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best answer that you received.

Answer (score 1):

The product of two convergent sequences is convergent. So it is true.

Comment: Ah, that was it, thank you.